# Separar consulta por mes e somar os resultados

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um banco de dados de pedidos que contem vários pedidos de varias datas, porem preciso que me list um relatorio separado por mes e suas respectivas somas na frente.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O campo data na tabela esta como Data datetime ( data_hora_pedido ) e os outros campos que serão somados como float ( deposistos,lucro,fornecedor )

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pedidos";
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { }
```

Comment: Obs: na imagem o mês está escrito "Fevereio" ao invés de "Fevereiro"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Primeiro eu não utilizaria `float` para esse tipo de dados.* Mas, para somar tudo por mês/ano basta que utilize o `GROUP BY`, por exemplo:

```
SELECT SUM(`depositos`), 
       SUM(`lucro`), 
       SUM(`fornecedor`), 
       MONTHNAME(data_hora_pedido) AS `Mes` 
FROM   pedidos
GROUP  BY YEAR(`data_hora_pedido`), 
          MONTH(`data_hora_pedido`)
```

O `YEAR(), MONTH()` vai agrupar pelas datas e o `SUM()` irá somar os dados da tabela e o `MONTHNAME()` irá retornar o nome do mês. Se quiser que os nomes dos meses estejam em português defina o `lc_time_names` para `pt_BR`.

Comment: O que vc me sugere para alterar o float?

Comment: +1 pelo função `MONTHNAME` que eu não conhecia.

Answer (score 0):

Basta fazer um select com group by mes, você não deu muitas informações sobre o problema mas baseando-se na sua imagem e nos dados que você escreveu, eu fiz um exemplo funcionando para você [no SQLFiddle aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcfd10/1)

Segue o código SQL que foi gerado para visualização direta nesta resposta:

```
select sum(depositos) as total_depositos,
       sum(lucro) as total_lucro,
       sum(fornecedor) as total_fornecedor,
       depositos,
       lucro,
       fornecedor,
       CASE extract(MONTH from data_hora_pedido)
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Janeiro'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Fevereiro'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'Março'
         WHEN 4 THEN 'Abril'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'Maio'
         WHEN 6 THEN 'Junho'
         WHEN 7 THEN 'Julho'
         WHEN 8 THEN 'Agosto'
         WHEN 9 THEN 'Setembro'
         WHEN 10 THEN 'Outubro'
         WHEN 11 THEN 'Novembro'
         WHEN 12 THEN 'Dezembro'
       END AS mes
from pedidos
group by mes
```

Answer (score 0):

Como ficaria então aplicado no PHP acima?

$sql = "select sum(depositos) as total_depositos,
sum(lucro) as total_lucro,
sum(fornecedor) as total_fornecedor,
depositos,
lucro,
fornecedor,
CASE extract(MONTH from data_hora_pedido)
WHEN 1 THEN 'Janeiro'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Fevereiro'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Março'
WHEN 4 THEN 'Abril'
WHEN 5 THEN 'Maio'
WHEN 6 THEN 'Junho'
WHEN 7 THEN 'Julho'
WHEN 8 THEN 'Agosto'
WHEN 9 THEN 'Setembro'
WHEN 10 THEN 'Outubro'
WHEN 11 THEN 'Novembro'
WHEN 12 THEN 'Dezembro'
END AS mes
from pedidos
group by mes";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { }

?